# problem with django after ondrive file moving to new folder

Tags: python-3.x, django

Does anyone could help me with below ? I tried all i found already and no luck....
Basically some time ago my company enforces use onedrive and all files where moved from my /Desktop to /One Drive/Desktop ... i figured out how to change all thing to get Django working again and python manage runserver works fine but when i try to migrate db i got something like below...i am using Pycharm and maybe something in settings of Pycharm is still related with old files location ? venv is using my new onedrive folder but errors in screen are related with my old folder location, really appreciate of any help to fix that problem [Pycharm error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8alu7.jpg)

Checked all Django settings related fixes but no luck for now